# How to create new combo box object in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

My code is as below

Dim cb as new ComboBox

cb.AddItem("item1")

I get Error :'Object required'

Someone pls help

Thanks.

Comment: Why make it programatically, can't you add the combobox in designer view?

Comment: For some logic reason, I need to have the userNames in the Form combo box and the userIds in a programmatic (runtime) combo box.

Comment: You can always have the runtime combobox hidden, and just display and populate it as needed. It's way simpler than creating comboboxes on-the-fly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In access you cannot create components programmatically. If you want to add components at runtime you have to either create them beforehand in the editor and hide them or you can programmatically open the form in designmode, add a component, save ot and then reopen it in runmode.
Its one of the biggest flaw in access as a Rapid Development Environment.